# Creating a dictionary type from an array type

Tags: typescript

Say one has a simple object type, `X`, and a function to create an explicitly-typed array of `X`, `createXList`, as follows:

```js
type X = Readonly<{
  a: string
  b: string
}>

type XList = Readonly<X[]>

// TS workaround to create an explicitly-typed X
const createXList = <TXList extends XList>(xList: TXList): TXList => xList
*/
```

One can then create an explicitly-typed array of `X`, say `xList`, like so:

```js
const xList = createXList([
  { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' },
  { a: 'fizz', b: 'buzz' },
] as const)
/*
const xList: readonly [{
    readonly a: "foo";
    readonly b: "bar";
}, {
    readonly a: "fizz";
    readonly b: "buzz";
}]
```

The question is: How would one create a type for a dictionary where each key is the concatenation of the `a` and `b` properties, and the value is simply the value of the array that was used to create each key in the dictionary, *while still keeping the explicit typing*. For example:

```js
type XListToXDict<T extends XList> = { /* some magic */ }

type Test = XListToXDict<typeof xList>
/*
{
  "foobar": { a: "foo", b: "bar" };
  "fizzbuzz": { a: "fizz", b: "buzz" };
}
*/
```

So, for example, the type to create a key for a particular `X` is:

```js
type XToKey<T extends X> = `${T['a']}${T['b']}`
```

Notes:

One would assume that one could do the following to at least extract the keys for the dictionary (using above `XToKey`):

```js
type XListToKeys<T extends XList> = XToKey<T[number]>
```

But this fails due to it instead generating all possible combinations of `a` and `b` (in the specific case of `xList`, that is `"foobar" | "foobuzz" | "fizzbar" | "fizzbuzz"`).

There is then the challenge of selecting a specific item from the array for each value in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a mapped type and renaming the key names with `as`.

```
type XListToXDict<T extends XList> = {
  [K in keyof T & `${bigint}` as T[K] extends { a: infer A, b: infer B } 
    ? `${A & string}${B & string}` 
    : never
  ]: T[K]
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UBKECGATA9gOwDYgB4BvAKCilQC4oBnYAJwEtsBzMqAI2rqdZIF8AfCRKhIsADKM6CZGix5CMANoBdYaPDQYUugBVMMACKMAxsAJ6oEAB7AI2dDUnTgg2aXLKA0lGZQAawgQTAAzKCsAMigAAwASIg5GFmZgfhiKZz0fVWs7BycoIgpqZlCIeigAQQAaTlLscsqAIX4odnIAfliEqqhonmYWfgTm-toGIfT28nJqbAgANwr2VWps71UBETFoPQAGWR1XA2MzC2VPWfp5HHwSqAAiUMxMR4BuDqgbjDuQeqeHFQ9A+AjqV3IPwU9yoT1CjAAXgjQbNvrdFADHhwAK5I0H8dRAA)

Comment: Thanks Tobias. What is the & \`${bigint\}` doing here?

Comment: `keyof` of arrays will lead to a lot of stuff we don't need like `length` and `pop`. The bigint thing lets us filter only array indizes like `"0"` or `"1"`

Comment: That seems like quite the dodgy workaround, no?